# Connection Error with MYSQLODBC Driver3.5

Tags: eclipse, odbc

I am trying to connect it to Eclipse Luna with Mysql for performing operation.
I am trying to connect ODBC Driver 3.5 32bit & its giving me error , when I try with ODBC 3.5 driver 64bit is connected to the database. 
My system is 64bit. I think the issue is with compatibility. Is there a solution for this issue?[image]

Comment: Maybe this: http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/12403/odbc-driver-could-not-be-loaded-due-to-system-error-code-126 ?

Comment: @FelipeAugusto I tried the solution provided but it didnt work in my case